# Unexpected output when transforming char which is larger than 127 to NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, char

```
    unichar temp=233;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",temp];

    //Type of 'temp" changed from unichar to char do not affects the output no matter it's char or unichar
```

output:
NSString:0xc388 ,not expected 0xE9
       length:1

We need to sent a pile of data as a packet, '233' should be sent as a **single-byte** data.

Comment: From the last line, it sounds like you're just sending data and it's not really suppose to represent text (ie: unichar).  So, uhm, why create an NSString instead of an NSData?!

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
+ (id)stringWithCharacters:(const unichar *)chars length:(NSUInteger)length
```

Because the input is an array, start with this:

```
unichar temp[] = {233};
```